# Return JSON data based on GeoDjango Queryset

Tags: python, python-2.x, json, django

My code below returns a JSON data based on user's input or query in my HTML page or template. However, I need to modify or do some tweaking with my JSON data in order for me to use it in my [datatables plugin](https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap). I am using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) to reconstruct the JSON data.

```
def brgy_info(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        get_muni = request.GET.get('munisipyo',default='All')
        get_brgy_id = request.GET.get('brgy_id')
        get_bldg_type = request.GET.getlist('bldg_type[]', default='All')   

        reference_high = FloodHazard.objects.filter(hazard='High')
        reference_medium = FloodHazard.objects.filter(hazard='Medium')
        reference_low = FloodHazard.objects.filter(hazard='Low')

        #get all ids based on filter
        ids_high = reference_high.values_list('id', flat=True)
        ids_medium = reference_medium.values_list('id', flat=True)
        ids_low = reference_low.values_list('id', flat=True)

        # create a list
        to_json = []
        args = []

        if get_muni != 'All Municipalities':
            args.append(Q(municipali=get_muni))

        if get_brgy_id not in ["Select Barangay","All Barangay"]:
            args.append(Q(brgy_locat=get_brgy_id))

        if get_bldg_type != 'All':      
            args.append(Q(bldg_type__in=get_bldg_type))

        # this code is results a messy JSON data that need underscore.js to manipulate
        # in order for us to use datatables
        for myid in ids_high:
            getgeom = FloodHazard.objects.get(id=myid).geom
            response_high = list(PolyStructures.objects.filter(geom__within=getgeom, *args).values(
                'bldg_type','bldg_name').annotate(count=Count('bldg_name')))
            for entry in response_high:
                entry['type'] = 'High'
                to_json.append(response_high)


        for myid in ids_medium:
            getgeom = FloodHazard.objects.get(id=myid).geom
            response_medium = list(PolyStructures.objects.filter(geom__within=getgeom, *args).values(
                'bldg_type','bldg_name').annotate(count=Count('bldg_name')))
            for entry in response_medium:
                entry['type'] = 'Medium'
                to_json.append(response_medium)

        for myid in ids_low:
            getgeom = FloodHazard.objects.get(id=myid).geom
            response_low = list(PolyStructures.objects.filter(geom__within=getgeom, *args).values(
                'bldg_type','bldg_name').annotate(count=Count('bldg_name')))
            for entry in response_low:
                entry['type'] = 'Low'
                to_json.append(response_low)


        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list(to_json)), content_type='application/json')
```

I find it very taskful for my page, without using underscore.js. This is the snippet of the JSON data result, which is just a sample based on this query:

> `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cnt_bldg/?brgy_id=Katugasan&munisipyo=Cabadbaran+City`

```
[
    [
        {
            "count": 1,
            "type": "Low",
            "bldg_name": "",
            "bldg_type": ""
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "count": 1,
            "type": "Low",
            "bldg_name": "Katugasan Multi-Purpose Gym",
            "bldg_type": "Sport Center/Gymnasium/Covered Court"
        },
        {
            "count": 16,
            "type": "Low",
            "bldg_name": "",
            "bldg_type": ""
        },
        {
            "count": 5,
            "type": "Low",
            "bldg_name": "Katugasan Elementary School",
            "bldg_type": "School"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "count": 1,
            "type": "Low",
            "bldg_name": "Katugasan Multi-Purpose Gym",
            "bldg_type": "Sport Center/Gymnasium/Covered Court"
        },
        {
            "count": 16,
            "type": "Low",
            "bldg_name": "",
            "bldg_type": ""
        },
        {
            "count": 5,
            "type": "Low",
            "bldg_name": "Katugasan Elementary School",
            "bldg_type": "School"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "count": 1,
            "type": "Low",
            "bldg_name": "Katugasan Multi-Purpose Gym",
            "bldg_type": "Sport Center/Gymnasium/Covered Court"
        },
        {
            "count": 16,
            "type": "Low",
            "bldg_name": "",
            "bldg_type": ""
        },
        {
            "count": 5,
            "type": "Low",
            "bldg_name": "Katugasan Elementary School",
            "bldg_type": "School"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "count": 3,
            "type": "Low",
            "bldg_name": "",
            "bldg_type": ""
        }
    ]
]
```

Some values were duplicated, so how do I remove the duplicates? Any ideas to simplify this code for optimization purposes?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. Nice first post; keep it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of repeated code which does not respect one of the main principle of software engineering : [Don't Repeat Yourself (aka DRY)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

I might be wrong but I have the feeling that the whole code about hazard being High/Medium/Low can be re-written :

```
    hazard_levels = ['High', 'Medium', 'Low']
    for hazard_level in hazard_levels:
        reference = FloodHazard.objects.filter(hazard=hazard_level)
        ids = reference.values_list('id', flat=True)
        for myid in ids:
            getgeom = FloodHazard.objects.get(id=myid).geom
            response = list(PolyStructures.objects.filter(geom__within=getgeom, *args).values(
                'bldg_type','bldg_name').annotate(count=Count('bldg_name')))
            for entry in response:
                entry['type'] = hazard_level
                to_json.append(response)
```

---

Your code does not do anything in the request method is not GET, is this normal ? Should it raise an exception ?

Comment: I will try that. Yes, you are right. I think it is much better if it raise an exception but I just use this function in my Ajax script. In which it returns a bunch of JSON data.